# why is this array index element is being displayed instead of throwing an error, even when the index values exceeds the given array size?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    a[20]=20;
    cout<<a[20];
}
```

Intially I thought that when 
`a[20]=20;`

is given the size of the array increases,but using sizeof() function

`cout<<sizeof(a)//sizeof(a[0]);`

I found that the size is of a[10] only. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The "size" is not changed. You just write outside of the array in the memory. In general you should not do that because you can't predict which memory you change by doing this.

But the size of a array is never increased in C. If you want a bigger one, you have to reserve a new one with more space in the memory.